# Vuejs SPA Change meta tag content from third party api

Tags: vuejs2

I've tried to change meta tag content like

```
document.title = response.data.seo_page_title[0].text;
document.head.querySelector('meta[name=description]').content = response.data.seo_description;
```

it change the content when inspect the page but not when i use view soure. So Google, FB and Twitter can't recognize the updated content and doesn't load the proper text when i try to share the page on social media.

Answer (score 0):

`View Source` shows the original source that has been fetched from the network - it is not the current snapshot of the page. As you have noticed - the current snapshot of the page is available in the DevTools. If you need Google / FB / etc. to see the proper text - you will have to produce this text on the server side (when composing the HTML template) instead of in the browser.

Comment: Could you please provide some example how can we achieve with serverside?

Comment: For server-side rendering (SSR) you can use Nuxt (https://nuxtjs.org/). Dynamically changing the content of the meta tag for each route will not work (as you have already noticed).